# Long delay between Spark driver + executor allocation and an initial stage starting

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

In the Spark UI for one of my applications, I reliably see a long delay (10 - 15 minutes) between allocation of a driver to the application and the first stage starting. What situations might cause a delay like this? I'm not sure if this is related, but I commonly see the following message in the driver logs:

```
diagnostics: [Sat Feb 25 17:17:56 +0000 2023] Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Queue's AM resource limit exceeded.  Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:57344, vCores:1, max vCores:8>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:366592, vCores:1>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:366592, vCores:1>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:344064, vCores:6>
```

Spark UI screenshot with delay

[image: 1]

I'm using Spark on AWS EMR for reference.

I started multiple applications and each time, I see this unreasonable delay from driver allocation to the first stage beginning. I expect the gap to be much shorter if there's a gap at all.